# Handle varying shapes in jax numpy arrays (jit compatible)

Tags: python, arrays, shapes, jit, jax

**Important note:** I need everything to be jit compatible here, otherwise my problem is trivial :)

I have a jax numpy array such as:

```
a = jnp.array([1,5,3,4,5,6,7,2,9])
```

First I filter it considering a value, let's assume that I only keep values that are < 5

```
a = jnp.where((a < 5), x=a, y=jnp.nan)
# a is now [ 1. nan  3.  4. nan nan nan  2. nan]
```

I want to keep only non-nan values: `[ 1.  3.  4.  2.]` and I will then use this array for other operations.

But more importantly, during execution of my program, this code will be executed multiple  times with a threshold value that will change (i.e. it won't always be 5).

Hence, the shape of the final array will change too. Here is my problem with jit compilation, I don't know how to make it jit compatible since the shape depends on how many elements comply to the threshold condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JAX's JIT is not currently compatible with arrays of dynamic (data-dependent) shape, so there is no way to do what your question asks.

There is some experimental work in progress on handling dynamic shapes within JAX transforms like JIT (see https://github.com/google/jax/pull/9335) but I'm not certain when it will be available to use.

The usual workaround for this is to re-express your computations in terms of statically-shaped arrays with a fill value; for example, you could use something like this:

```python
a = jnp.where((a < 5), size=len(a), fill_value=np.nan)
```

This will create an array of the same length as `a`, with non-nan values at the front, and filled with `nan` values at the end.